# Pandas read multiple CSV files, compute percent change for a column in each file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of CSV files in multiple locations, but all folders have the same format below where the only difference in folder name is the asset/symbol being used. So I'm trying to use a wildcard (% assets) to search for each folder, **as well as the most recent file in that folder**. I then want to compute percent change for the 'Close' column period-by-period for each asset in its own, separate DataFrame.

Each file looks like this:

```
Ticker  Date/Time   Close
ES U7   3/14/2017 4:44  2365.5
ES U7   3/14/2017 6:14  2360
ES U7   3/14/2017 6:29  2362.25
ES U7   3/14/2017 7:44  2361.25
ES U7   3/14/2017 7:59  2359.25
ES U7   3/14/2017 8:14  2357.25
ES U7   3/14/2017 8:29  2355
ES U7   3/14/2017 8:44  2353.75
ES U7   3/14/2017 8:59  2354.75
ES U7   3/14/2017 9:14  2354.5
ES U7   3/14/2017 9:29  2359.25
ES U7   3/14/2017 9:44  2358.5
ES U7   3/14/2017 9:59  2359
ES U7   3/14/2017 10:14 2355.5
```

My code below is trying to a. read each csv file (convert to dataframe), and b. compute percent change on the 'Close' column. So I want this code to pick up each file for 'VX', 'ES' and 'ZN' symbols:

```
def read_files():

    Assets = ['ZN','VX','ES']

    path = r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Exported_Data\%s\*.csv" % Assets
    allfiles = (max(glob.iglob(path), key=os.path.getctime))

    list_ = []

    for file_ in allFiles:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None)
        list_.append(df)    

    for asset in assets:
        df1['Returns'] = Asset['Close'].pct_change()
```

I get an error at the 'allfiles' definition:

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Can someone assist me in applying the for loops/function across multiple symbols?

Comment: Note that `r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Exported_Data\%s\*.csv" % Assets` isn't doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is how you're reading your files. If you want to load every single file, you probably don't want to use things like `max` there. Furthermore, `string % Assets` is going to insert a stringified version of the list as-is, without any intricate substitution as you'd expect.

---

```
assets = ['ZN','VX','ES']
path = r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Exported_Data\%s\*.csv"

files = []
for a in assets:
    files.extend(glob.iglob(path % a))

df_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(df_list)
```